# Client Side clock using server side system time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Im working in a .Net environment, and on my aspx page I would like to add a running digital clock w//seconds , but I need it to use the server side time. Whats the best approach for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you assume that time on the server runs at the same pace as time on the client? (ie, they aren't moving at relativistic speeds)

Comment: How accurate you won it ? For real accurate you need to implement some protocol that can calculate not only the get of the time, but also the delay to get that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the AJAX UpdatePanel?

MSDN: [Tutorial: How to refresh an UpdatePanel control at a timed interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx)

It might be overkill to update every second. Maybe implement it so that it polls the server to check the server and the client times are still sync'd and if not, update the client page?

Comment: Maybe the UpdatePanel is looks like an easy solution, but please don't ! Make some ajax call and a small javascript and there you go.

Answer (score 5):

Take a [**moment**](http://momentjs.com/) to look at this javascript library.

You would just need to provide your server-side time to your javascript code, probably through something like a data-attribute

i.e:

```
<html data-server-time="@Model.ServerTime">
```

and then your JS should simply be (assuming jQuery, and moment):

```
var date = $('html').data('server-time');
var start = new Date();

var updateTime = function (){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var now = moment(date).add(new Date() - start).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')
        $('.target').text(now);
        updateTime();
    },1000);
}

$(function(){
    updateTime();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQsE6/)

This way you would be using the server time but you wouldn't need to request it more than once per page load, avoiding unnecessary AJAX calls. Unless your server has a nuclear grade clock or something like that.

Comment: This assumes that time at the server is passing at the same rate. :)

Comment: Well, unless he needs insanely accuracy, or the server is time-travelling in hyper-space, this should do.