# Using classic asp to get server time inside javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

This one has me yanking my hair out. I placed the following classic ASP code inside the head of my document to get the server time for use in javascript... and it works, the first time. Later when the javascript calls the same function inside javascript I get the time but 2 minutes off!

first time around inside the head (OK)

```
    <% 
Dim servertime, d
    d = Now 
    servertime = Cstr(Right("00" & Hour(d), 2) & ":" & Right("00" & Minute(d), 2) & ":" & Right("00" & Second(d), 2)) 'parse out hh:mm:ss
%>

    <script>
window.servertime = '<%=servertime%>'; // set servertime to server time duh!
    </script>
```

Later inside a javascript function:

```
    <% 
    d = Now 
    servertime = Cstr(Right("00" & Hour(d), 2) & ":" & Right("00" & Minute(d), 2) & ":" & Right("00" & Second(d), 2)) 'parse out hh:mm:ss
%>

window.servertime = '<%=servertime%>'; // get the server time again!
```

Every time the second function runs its off by 2 minutes!

Comment: asp-classic?! **on 2013?!** I think you really do have a problem with the time...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385628/client-side-clock-using-server-side-system-time/14385781#14385781

Comment: I still speak english and its a bit older : )

Comment: @hillcreative you realize that the ASP stuff is resolved **at the server**, and once it gets to the browser those ASP expressions are long gone, right?

Comment: Mike, thanks for the suggestion but that code snippet is so far out from what I'm trying to do. Any suggestions on how I should improve my code?

Comment: Yeah Pointy, I'm using the server side instead of the client because I can trust the server time for my calculations between a start time and the time now. The client could also be in a different time zone.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to query the _current_ server time every time you call some JS code?

Comment: Every time a song changes it calls a JS function which includes the ASP code to get the server time. That way I can compare it to the song start time to get the difference between actual start and time now.

Comment: PS. It's almost like the server time that comes back can be off by as much as 2-4 minutes on subsequent requests, but the first time the page runs its OK ! Can it be caching results somehow?

Comment: @hillcreative ASP (especially IIS) parses _ALL_ your code **before** sending the _parsed result_ to client browsers. You can easily find out what happen if you view-source in your browser. So whatever you write, once it reaches client's side, it's (at some point) "static".

Comment: So are you saying that I can't dynamically update the server time from a client running JS? It will just keep returning the original server time from the first request? I guess thats why a page refresh gets me the correct server time but a js function can't get updated time...

Comment: Sound of me slapping my forehead! I should use a .get() to retrieve the time from a server side script!  Yikes I feel stupid!!

Answer (score 1):

The servertime variable is calculated when the page is initially rendered, it will only be updated when the page is called again.

This means there are a couple of things you could do if you want to use the current server time:

1. When the page loads grab the server time, but also grab the javascript local time. when you want to refresh the time add the difference between now and the initial local time to the original server time... it won't be 100% accurate but it'll be close.
2. Slightly more complicated.. have a page on the server that does nothing but return the current time and when you want to display the server time from javascript make an AJAX call (e.g. using jQuery) to grab that and display it.

Answer (score 1):

May this will help. I am not sure what you need the time for... I used that to give a 2-minute advance warning inside an asp page when the user session is about to expire.

```
<%
advanceWarning = 2 
jsTimeout = (session.timeout - advanceWarning) * 60000 
%> 
<script>window.setTimeout("alert('Security Message at <%=time%> (EST): You have been idle for too long on the website. For your security, your session will expire in 2 minutes and you will be automatically logged out if you continue to remain idle!');",<%=jsTimeout%>);</script>
```